# How to fill with gradient color curvilinear trapezoid area in javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts

I have a chart where I need to fill with color the area under chart line.

One can said that I can use polygon approach. So, I can decompose my curvilinear trapezoid area under chart line into polygons using `moveTo` and `lineTo` and just `ctx.fill()` it.

But there is two cons of this approach:

1) Performance. I need to create and process every polygon separately each time when chart draws. It is pretty often.

2) I can't fill the whole section under chart line with the common gradient. But this is exactly what I need.

So, I am searching the function that will:

1) Get all visible chart vertices (can be extracted from data Array for the chart)

2) Calculate the color (for example alpha component) depending on current pixel y-coordinate under chart line

3) Fill pixels under chart line with corresponding color.

I can't use webgl in my situation. Just regular canvas 2d context.

I understand, that maybe I'm asking too much. But I hope that I'm not the first one with the same problem.

**Edit:**

I need to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: can you share a graphical visualization of your expected chart ?

Comment: I see only one path in this image, why can't you fill it ? (okay maybe two with the stroke, but simply `stroke()` first, then `lineTo(right, bottom); lineTo(left, bottom);` and finally `fill()`

Comment: @Kaiido, your approch doesn't support true curvilinear charts. For example sin(x) or even -x^2.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see why. Could you show me an example of something you think would not work with my way, and how you'd graphically represent it ? https://jsfiddle.net/axdqw2ey/1/

Comment: @Kaiido, I realized that curvilinear charts like sin(x) are also constructed with lineTo, moveTo. Well, maybe I should try.

Comment: Yes, and even if you decide to go with cubicBezierCurveTo, it would still be the same : stroke before you close your path, and then fill.